# Console application crashing/not responding

Tags: c#

stack overflow community.

I am writing a program that convert fahrenheit temperature into celsius and celsius into fahrenheit. The program has a simple menu and gets the user input to select an option. I implemented a little do-while loop in case that the user enters an invalid option. If the user selects 1, 2, or 3 (which are the three valid options) the program will run an if statement, execute the block code within it, and break the loop. However, if the user enters anything else (an invalid option) the program will execute the block code in else and then it will go back to the beginning of the loop (Choose an option) freezing or crashing in the process.

Here is the code:

```
// James Archbold
// Convert.cs
// A program to convert fahrenheit to celsius or celsius to fahrenheit
//16 February 2013

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Convert_Temperature
{
class Convert
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        float F, C;
        string option;

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nWelcome to 'Convert' program!");
            Console.WriteLine("***********************Menu**********************************");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Fahrenheit to Celsius");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Celsius to Fahrenheit");
            Console.WriteLine("3. Goodbye");

            Console.Write("\nPlease enter an option: ");
            option = Console.ReadLine();

            switch (option)
            {
                case "1":
                    Console.Write("Please enter your Fahrenheit temperature: ");
                    F = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    C = (5f / 9f) * (F - 32);
                    Console.WriteLine("The temperature is {0} degrees Celsius.", C);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;


                case "2":
                    Console.Write("Please enter your Celsius temperature: ");
                    C = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    F = 5f / 9f * C - 32;

                    Console.WriteLine("The temperature is {0} degrees Fahrenheit.", F);

                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;


                case "3":
                    Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;


                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid option!");
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Please press Enter to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

        } while (option != "3");

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I'm not fluent in C#, but I would expect your program to die with an exception thrown by `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`. So what does happen? crash or freeze? What happens if you step through your program in the debugger?

Comment: When I run the program in Visual C# express it will freeze and throw me back to what I assume is the debugger. On the other hand, when I compile the program in windows cmd the program will crash and throw me an "unhandled exception"

Comment: Program works fine for me, beside the `FormatException` that is thrown. Look at the second answer.

Comment: Have you guys tried with any other option than 1, 2, and 3?

Answer (score 3):

Your line, `option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`, will throw an exception if the entered text cannot be parsed. Consider using the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) method instead:

```
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out option) {
    option = -1; // Set option to represent an invalid option.
}
```

Comment: Should I change the variable assignment statement to this one?

Comment: By doing this I have obtained a similar result to declaring the variable as int, the program will display the "Please enter an option: This option is invalid" after entering any other number different than 1,2, or 3.

Answer (score 1):

Jameslat - As FlsZen has suggested in the comment above

Replace

```
option = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // Original code
```

with

```
if ( !int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out option))
{
    option = -1;
}
```

Using TryParse enables you to check if the operation succeeded or not by examining the return value which is of boolean type. A false return value indicates that the parsing was unsuccessful which in the code snippet assigns the value -1 to the variable named "option".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx